# DOM resets after submitting form with JavaScript to POST to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, dom, form-submit

After making changes to many elements with JS, eg. display :none; . Then submitting a hidden form with JS that POST to PHP variable. The page refreshes 
All the elements to their default style. So all the elements that had style changes with JS become visible again. Is this PHP or JS or the browser resetting the DOM (eg. index.php becomes index.php#)?  I would like to leave the php page in the current CSS state after submitting.

Solution should be PHP or JS (html CSS). I’m avoiding other solutions.

Comment: Without showing us your code we can't help you

Comment: If you are sending a form to PHP, without an HTTPxmlRequest, the page is reloaded. That's why